# magento site bottom is more blank space

Tags: css, magento, space

my magento site bottom has more blank space. i can't remove it. please help me to remove this. i think this bug coming from `<div class="menu-wrapper">` .this is the url http://classichotrodshop.qubitwebtechnologies.com/index.php/performance/heidts/heidts-df-208-red-front-disc-brake-kits.html

all pages displaying with this blank space. please anyone help me to fix this problem

thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...............................
hi now give

`#nav ul, #nav div`  **Css**

`overflow:hidden;`

As like this

```
#nav ul, #nav div{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[Now Result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5i7U.png)***

Answer (score 0):

Today I was in the same situation but got with an alternative that works too. For future problems with Magento responsive case.

This problem occurs (or one of the possible causes) when the responsive manual wrapper is overflowing in the bottom. And as [Rohit Azad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365428/rohit-azad) said earlier his solution is correct.

In Magento 1.9 you can find this HTML tag in the footer:

```
<nav id="yt-screennav"></nav>
```

This one is controlled with the CSS file called **ytc-bootstrap-responsive.css**

And you got to check the next point: **.yt_ressidebar_screennav #yt_screennav** and only add the clause said in the earlier post.

```
.yt_ressidebar_screennav #yt_screennav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #222;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -220px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}
```